# clicking on autocomplete list

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete, cursor

I have an autocomplete which does a query to DB....when doing a click on one of the entries displayed within the autocomplete I wanna take the item I clicked on and display it...for this I implemented onClickListener:

Here is my code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_from);

ContactListCursorAdapter adapter = new ContactListCursorAdapter(this,
                cursor);

        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

            @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int arg2,long arg3){



                System.out.println("Click la autocomplet pe :" +arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
            }

        });
```

But here is what my System.out displays:

```
Click la autocomplet pe :android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43c33e18


Click la autocomplet pe :android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43c33e18
```

Anyone has any idea of how could that be done cause this clearly is not working for me!

---

Here is my entire code:

What I'm doing is binding an autocomplete with a DB.....as soon as I start typing in my autocomplete there are displayed the content oof 2 columns from my DB....of course filtered with what I start typing:

public class Server8 extends MapActivity {
    DBAdapter db;
    CharSequence constraint1;
    MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    InitTask init_task=null;
    String user_id;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server8);

    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_from);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setMessage("I am thinking");

    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.createDatabase();
    db.openDataBase();
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllData2();

    textView.setHint("type route");
    textView.setThreshold(2);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mc = mapView.getController();

    mc.setZoom(10);

    ContactListCursorAdapter adapter = new ContactListCursorAdapter(this,
            cursor);

    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROWID_2);
            user_id = c.getString(nameCol);

            init_task = new InitTask();
            init_task.execute(db);

        }

    });


     Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View arg1) {
              System.out.println("Click pe butonul stop!");
            init_task.cancel(true);
         }
```

});

}

```
public void theRouteDraw(GeoPoint p) {
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17);

    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.invalidate();

}

class myOverlay extends Overlay {
    GeoPoint gp1;
    GeoPoint gp2;

    public myOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2) {

        this.gp1 = gp1;
        this.gp2 = gp2;

    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        Point from = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, from);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        Point to = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp2, to);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);
        mPaint.setAlpha(120);
        canvas.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y, mPaint);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    }

}

public class InitTask extends AsyncTask<DBAdapter, GeoPoint, Void> {
    List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    DBAdapter db;
    int latitude;
    int longitude;
    GeoPoint p;
    String TABLE_3;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(DBAdapter... db) {
        try {
            //db[0].openDataBase();
            Cursor c = db[0].getCursor3(db[0].TABLE_3, user_id);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    longitude = (int) Double.parseDouble(c.getString(1));
                    latitude = (int) Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2));
                    System.out.println("Valoarea latitudinii" + latitude
                            + longitude);
                    p = new GeoPoint(longitude, latitude);
                    publishProgress(p);
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                } while (c.moveToNext());

            }
            c.close();
            db[0].close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Eroare", "doInBackground", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(GeoPoint... progress1) {

        try {

            if (geoPointsArray.size() == 1) {

                mapView.getOverlays().add(
                        new myOverlay(geoPointsArray.get(0), geoPointsArray
                                .get(0)));
                theRouteDraw(progress1[0]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (geoPointsArray.size() > 1) {
            int i = geoPointsArray.size();

            List overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            overlays.add(new myOverlay(geoPointsArray.get(i - 1),
                    progress1[0]));
            theRouteDraw(progress1[0]);
        }

        geoPointsArray.add(progress1[0]);

    }
}

public class ContactListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements
        Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private TextView mName, mNumber;

    public ContactListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        Cursor c = getCursor();
        final LinearLayout ret = new LinearLayout(context);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mName = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);


        mNumber = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);

        ret.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout horizontal = new LinearLayout(context);
        horizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_SURSA);

        String name = c.getString(nameCol);

        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DATE));

        mName.setText(name);
        mNumber.setText(number);

        horizontal.addView(mName, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ret.addView(mNumber, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ret.addView(horizontal, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return ret;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_SURSA);

        String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);

        String number = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DATE));

        ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(0)).setText(number);
        LinearLayout horizontal = (LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) view)
                .getChildAt(1);
        ((TextView) horizontal.getChildAt(0)).setText(name);

    }


      public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
     int numcol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_SURSA); 
     String name = cursor.getString(numcol);
     return name;

     }


    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }

        String filter = "";
        if (constraint == null)
            filter = "";

        else
            filter = constraint.toString();

        Cursor cursor = db.getCursor(filter);
        return cursor;

    }

}

public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();

db.close();
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(init_task!=null){
    init_task.cancel(true);
  init_task=null;
    }
}




protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

### }

This is how my autocomplete acts when I click on it:

textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROWID_2);
            user_id = c.getString(nameCol);

            init_task = new InitTask();
            init_task.execute(db);

        }

    });
```

Comment: The error may be at Database. To get about the issue can you post more code?

Comment: Yes....but the code is quite loong.I've posted it on a previous question....I'll put the link in here...let me know if u understand

Comment: I think arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) returns a cursor... maybe you have to extract the data from it because using .toString() it only returns the name of the Object..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171023/using-an-autocomplete-to-query-in-a-db   ......the only improvement to this code is the listener added above...in rest is exactly this one!!!!

Comment: I don't know about that...cause arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) it hasn't too many methods for extracting.....it doesn't let me extract anything

Comment: I feel the issue is in database section. I have tried sample code. Its workinf I can get OnItemClick event also. Have a look on the url http://www.megaupload.com/?d=TXSMIF2Y

Comment: Well,I don't really know how this works..:-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@embry the onItemclickListener for this textview  will return the cursor not the item within the cursor.

In the custom cursor adaptor(ContactListCursorAdapter) you will be implementing a method called covertToString(Cursor).  this method dictates what is shown when the user clicks each entry in your autocomplete list. Here is where you can get the value selected.

```
@Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        // this method dictates what is shown when the user clicks each entry in your autocomplete list
        String name="";

              name =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column1"))
              Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));




        return name;
    }



public int getId(){     
     return Id;
 }
```

I get the id in convertToString(). and a method getId() to return the id. so in the main method

```
 AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_from);
 ContactListCursorAdapter adapter = new ContactListCursorAdapter(this,               cursor);
int Id = adapter.getDrugId();
```

This works for me. Iam not sure whether this is the right way.

Comment: I found a way so it works for me....it's a little different.But yes u are right onItemclickListener() returns a cursor.Anyway u  have a point and my accept~

Comment: @embry nice to know it works for you. can you share how you did it.is it similar or anything different?

Comment: I'll update my question....If u don't understand just ask for further details and I'll give it to you!

Comment: There u have the whole code ...and at the end is what u are interested on:)